# Angularjs ng-repeat shows n items n times

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm attempting to use ng-repeat in a couple of elements on my page.
For some reason it's showing each of the n elements n times and I cannot figure out why.
My array looks something like this:

```
$scope.fieldNames = ["Last_Name","First_Name","Email","Home_Phone","Cell_Phone"];
```

I have a select box that is filling n^2 times (I have tried using ng-options but cannot get it to work with the array):

```
<td>
<select ng-model="currentField" style="width: 100%">
                        <option ng-repeat="field in fieldNames">{{field}}</option>
                    </select>
<td>
```

Additionally this happens with the header row of my table.
But not with the member rows or the cells contained within.

```
<table class = "main-table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th ng-repeat = "field in fieldNames">{{field}}</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat = "member in members" >
            <td ng-repeat = "field in fieldNames">{{member[field]}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

If someone could please explain to me why this is happening and how to fix it I would be grateful. A working example of the ng-options would also be appreciated.

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of what happens, or preferably a working example on something like http://plnkr.co/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out that the reason each item was repeating n times is that both my page and the layout template I was using both had

```
<script type = "text/javascript" src =  https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.5/angular.min.js"> </script>
```

As a result angular was apparently loading twice and running the ng-repeat on the ng-repeat, hence all the additional entries.

Answer (score 2):

To work with a list of strings in `ng-options`, you need the comprehension expression looks like this

```
<select ng-model="currentField" ng-options="field for field in fieldNames"></select>
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/q3WTT/)**</kbd>

Comment: Thanks, this worked for the ng-options portion of the question. See my answer for details on the n^2 items.

Comment: @DocSmiley I created a demo for you, however I am not seeing that issue. Please check.

Comment: Sorry. I was unclear. This fixed the select box repeat issue. The repeating <th> and <td> were from a different issue that I addressed in my answer. Thank you for your time.